# How can i submit a form from frontend in magento?

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

i have created a simple custom module to store "title, date and content" from backend admin panel.
But now i want the same form to be displayed on frontend, and when user submits the form, it should store the information just like as added from backend, and show in the grid in backend .

In short, i want the information to be stored from backend as well frontend.

Can anyone please suggest any helpful links or tell me how to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make a form in a template file (.phtml) and display it on a page and have the form  submit to a controller that saves the data just like you save it on the adminhtml controller.

Comment: Sounds Great !!! i will give it a try and then will post back the results :)
anyways thanks

Comment: Can You Explain Properly